# Cómo superponer una foto en un contenedor?

Tags: css, flexbox, position

Me encuentro con el siguiente problema: quiero superponer una imagen en una caja/contenedor como se muestra aquí en la foto ubicada en la parte de arriba de la página [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi código hasta ahora, .chaco-container__plan corresponde al div ubicado al fondo y .chaco-flyer al div que contiene la imagen

```
    .chaco-container__plan {
    background-color: white;
    border: none;
    width: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    
}

.chaco-flyer {
    position: relative;
         
}
```

Gracias de antemano por la ayuda!!

Comment: Podrias hacerlo con la propiedad `z-index: 1000;` a la imagen

Answer (score 0):

Como dice cristian en los comentarios, para poder sobreponer cualquier elemento HTML sobre otro necesitas utilizar la propiedad CSS: `z-index`. Para utilizarla debes de asignarle un número al elemento que deseas sobreponer sobre otro, el número que utilices debe de ser mayor al elemento que quieras sobreponer, esto quiere decir que el elemento que se verá por detrás tendrá un número menor que el encimado, por ejemplo en tu caso, pudieras usar un `z-index: 10` para la imagen y en el rectángulo un `z-index: 0`, con esto la imagen estará por encima del rectángulo.

https://codepen.io/eduardonwa/pen/YzNmQzy

No siempre es obligatorio aplicar un `z-index` al elemento que irá por detrás ya que el default es **0** para todos los elementos HTML. Lo importante a recordar aquí es que si quieres tener elementos por encima de otros debes de utilizar un número `z-index` mayor al pasado.